# Restart MainActivity or application with singleTop.

Tags: java, android, android-intent

How can I restart my application or MainActivity when the activity have:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

I have tried:

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
```

But because of singleTop this not working, there is an other way to do this?

Comment: What is `getBaseContext()`? Are you trying to use a stale context object? Does it work if you create the Intent the way the documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#StartingAnActivity says: `i = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);` then addFlags and startActivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to restart with this may this will help u

```
Intent i = cntxt.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(cntxt.getPackageName() );
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            cntxt.startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 3):

I did my theme switcher like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Basically, I'm calling finish() first, and I'm using the exact same intent this activity was started with. That seems to do the trick?

UPDATE: As pointed out by Ralf below, Activity.recreate() is the way to go in API 11 and beyond. This is preferable if you're in an API11+ environment. You can still check the current version and call the code snippet above if you're in API 10 or below. (Please don't forget to up-vote Ralf's answer!)

```
public void reload() {

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    finish();

    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

or

```
private void restartFirstActivity()
 {
 Intent i = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
 .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getApplicationContext().getPackageName() );

 i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
 startActivity(i);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
 Intent finishIntent = new Intent( this,
                                activity_that_you_want_to_return.class);
 finishIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
 startActivity(finishIntent);
```

Comment: It closes the app without starting it